# Passing parameter from ionic app to an external html page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am working on an ionic app , and sharing an external html url on social platform from my ionic app . 
Now I want to share some parameters along with the shared link ,

so , can we share link along with the value that we want to pass ?

Comment: have you tried? Seems yes you can pass

Comment: Yes I have tried but that doesn't work , do you have any concept for that

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way to pass parameters via URLs is to use [Query String](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

By appending `?parametereName=value` to the end of a URL, you basically pass the parameter along with that URL, and with a proper handle the destination will be able to grab and use the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is Yes.

You can simply pass your value to any external URL using queryParams as I said in comment.

Here is sample example -

```
<a href='https://www.google.com/?example=hello' target='_blank'>Google </a>
```

[WORKING EXAMPLE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/external-url?file=src/app/app.component.html)